# Define curvature and curvature of a circle

Tags: differential-geometry

Question:(a) Define the curvature function $\kappa$ of a plane curve.

The curvature of $\kappa$ of a plane curve is the amount of turning in the osculating plane. In other words it decribes the speed of rotation.

Is how I defined it okay? I feel like I need more or something.

Question:(b) Determine the curvature function of the circle $\alpha(t)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)$.
To find our curvature we must find the derivative of $\alpha$;

$\alpha'(t)=(-r\sin t, r\cos t)$.

Now to find our constant we do the following:

$|\alpha'(t)|= \sqrt{r^2\sin^2 t+r^2\cos^2 t}= \sqrt{r^2(\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t)}= \sqrt{r^2}= r.$

Thus, we get the arc-length as,

$s= \int_{0}^{t}r dt= rt \bigg |^t_0= rt.$

So, we can write $t= \dfrac{s}{r}$. Using the value of $t$ we substitute it into $\beta$ such that it is a curve parametrized by arc length,

$\beta(s)=(r\cos\dfrac{s}{r}, r\sin\dfrac{s}{r}).$

Using this we find the derivative to be,

$\beta'(s)=(-\sin\dfrac{s}{r}, \cos\dfrac{s}{r}).$

Looking for our constant we get,

$|\beta'(s)|=\sqrt{(-\sin\dfrac{s}{r})^2+\cos^2\dfrac{s}{r}}= \sqrt{1}=1 ,\ \ \ \forall s.$

Finding our second derivative we get,

$\beta"(s)=(-\dfrac{1}{r}\cos\dfrac{s}{r}, -\dfrac{1}{r}\sin\dfrac{s}{r}).$

$|\beta"(s)|=\sqrt{(-\dfrac{1}{r}\cos\dfrac{s}{r})^2+ (-\dfrac{1}{r}\sin\dfrac{s}{r})^2}= \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{r^2}}= \dfrac{1}{r}$

Therefore, we see that the curvature $\kappa$ of the circle is a constant,$\dfrac{1}{r}$.

Is my work okay? I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

For the most part this is fine, although I have a few items of feedback:

1. Curvature is often defined as a positive quantity, as you have here. For several reasons (uniqueness of a curves up to rigid motions given curvature; extensibility to higher dimensions, etc) the *signed* curvatures is often more useful. You should check which of these your professor is expecting for this problem (if the curvature is signed, then the curvature of a circle will depend on both its radius and orientation.)
2. Your definition is a bit off: mathematical definitions must be very precise; what *precisely* do you mean by "amount of turning"?
3. Several times you say you are "finding a constant" when you derive the arc length of a curve. I don't understand what you mean by that -- arc length is not constant, nor, generally, is the norm of the derivative of a curve constant (that it is a constant for the particular parameterization of the circle provided by your professor is a happy accident). Otherwise your work in reparameterizing the curve is correct, though.